# Trying to append the contents of multiple files in a folder to a new file

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a script in ruby that reads through the files in a folder, and merges them into an individual file.

This is what i've come up with

```
File.open('authorized_keys','a') do |mergedfile|
  @files = Dir.glob('/home/<user>/ruby_script/*.keys')
  for file in @files
    text = File.open(file, 'r').read
    text.each_line do |line|
      mergedfile << line
    end
  end
end
```

The idea is that the script will download public key files from github for our developers, merge them into an authorized_keys file which we'll then scp to our cloud servers.

The problem i'm having is that when the authorized_key file is generated, some of the ssh keys are on new lines, some are on the same line as others.

I've checked the downloaded files, and each key is on its' own line

How can I ensure that each key is on it's own line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines other than the last one in a file are surely terminated with an endline character (otherwise, they will not be recognized as a line), so your problem is that the end of a file is not necessarily an endline character. To ensure that, change the line

```
text = File.open(file, 'r').read
```

to

```
text = File.open(file, 'r').read.sub(/#$/?\z/, $/)
```

Comment: +1, BTW, `/\n?\z/, "\n"` seems more appropriate if you use text mode because `$/` string will be converted to `"\n"` in text mode.

Comment: @falsetru I think you mean `/\n?\z/`. And that is only on UNIX.

Comment: I misunderstood `$/`. `$/` == `"\n"` even in Windows. I thought `$/` is like [`os.linesep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep) in Python.

Answer (score 6):

This would more easily be done using `cat` at the command line. You can easily concatenate all the files together into one file. This is from `man cat` at the command-line:

```
The command:

      cat file1 file2 > file3

will sequentially print the contents of file1 and file2 to the file file3,
truncating file3 if it already exists.  See the manual page for your shell
(i.e., sh(1)) for more information on redirection.
```

You could easily create the appropriate command from an array of files in the directory, and then create the command and execute it in a sub-shell via backticks or the `%x` command.

Something like:

```
require 'dir'

files = Dir['/path/to/files.*'].select{ |f| File.file?(f) }.join(' ')
`cat #{ files } > new_file`
```

Your original code could be rewritten more succinctly as:

```
File.open('authorized_keys','a') do |mergedfile|
  Dir.glob('/home/<user>/ruby_script/*.keys').each do |file|
    mergedfile.write(File.read(file))
  end
end
```

The difference (and problem) with your code is the `read` statement. That pulls an entire file into memory. If that file is larger than the available memory your program will stop. Badly. There are ways to work around that using `foreach` instead of `read`, such as:

```
File.open('authorized_keys','a') do |mergedfile|
  Dir.glob('/home/<user>/ruby_script/*.keys').each do |file|
    File.foreach(file) do |li|
      mergedfile.write(li)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) to remove trailing newline, then add newline (`"\n"` or `$/`):

```
"abc\n".chomp + "\n" # => "abc\n"
"abc".chomp + "\n" # => "abc\n"
```

---

```
mergedfile << line.chomp + "\n"
```